# mousewheel MozMousePixelScroll not getting direction parameter on Dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that turns a div into a scrolling number div.

I want to control the scroll so I create the elements and add them to the the div in which the plugin is being applied to.

In my plugin, I bind a mousewheel and MozMousePixelScroll event using .on().

The problem is, when I use just mouse wheel on an element that is not added dynamically, I am able to get not only the detail of the event, but also a number representing the direction of the scroll...

```
$('.scale_window',this).first().on( "mousewheel",function(data,dirNum){

console.log(data);
console.log(dirNum);

}
```

This would output the scroll data object and then a number of -1 or 1 for the dirNum depending on the direciton of the scroll...

When I use this code on a dynamic event, I can no longer get the dirNum parameter.

```
   $('.scale_window',this).first().on(  "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll",function(data,dirNum){

    console.log(data);
    console.log(dirNum);

    }
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is?